Pub/Sub benchmark: why the benchmark of killing connection each time is better than using single connection
I am a newbie of GCP Pub/Sub, and I try to test the benchmarh of publish message.
we have two scenario below:
both scenario will publish 6 messages.
Scenario 1: create pubsubClient, then publish 6 message to the pubsub. After that kill the client.
Scenario 2:  for each message, create new pubcubclient, after message published close the client.
the benchmark code can be found below:
func BenchmarkPublish(b *testing.B) {
    os.Setenv("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8085")

    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, ProjectID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("can't create client: ", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    topic := client.Topic(TopicID)

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, fruit := range fruits {
            err := Publish(os.Stdout, ctx, TopicID, topic, fruit)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln("can't publish message: ", err)
            }
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkPublishAndKillConnectionEachTime(b *testing.B) {
    os.Setenv("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8085")

    ctx := context.Background()

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, fruit := range fruits {
            client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, ProjectID)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln("can't create client: ", err)
            }
            topic := client.Topic(TopicID)

            err = Publish(os.Stdout, ctx, TopicID, topic, fruit)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln("can't publish message: ", err)
            }
            client.Close()
        }
    }
}

This is Publish function:
func Publish(w io.Writer, ctx context.Context, topicID string, t *pubsub.Topic, msg string) error {
    // projectID := "my-project-id"
    // topicID := "my-topic"
    // msg := "Hello World"

    result := t.Publish(ctx, &pubsub.Message{
        Data: []byte(msg),
    })
    id, err := result.Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("pubsub: result.Get: %w", err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Published a message; msg ID: %v\n", id)
    return nil
}

In my mind, the BenchmarkPublish should run faster than BenchmarkPublishAndKillConnectionEachTime. but Actually BenchmarkPublish is slower one.
this is benchmark:


My question is Why  the benchmark of killing connection each time is better than using single connection? In my view, If we do create and close client, it should consume a bit of compute resources. So it should slower than maintaining a PubsubClient until all publish operations finished.

They both take a bit of time and are near each other, so I won't read too much in it. Profile where the time is spent to learn more instead of taking a micro benchmark more serious than you should.

There are a few things I'd point out here:

Your calling result.Get(ctx) in Publish means that you are waiting for each message to return synchronously when, as eik mentions, the client library publishes asynchronously. The library waits for more messages to put into a single batch before sending messages (or until PublishSettings.DelayThreshold passes). By default, PublishSettings.DelayThreshold is 10 milliseconds, so your time is probably going to be dominated by all of that waiting and it is the same in both scenarios.
You are using the emulator. The emulator is going to hide some of the parts that do take longer when establishing a connection, e.g., negotiating a secure connection with authentication. In general, I would suggest testing against the service itself to get a more realistic view on the differences between these two pieces of code.
Doing just six publishes isn't really going to be enough to establish a good comparison. That is a very tiny number and so some of the efficiencies of reusing the publisher are not going to be as readily visible. I would recommend doing at least 1000.


Thank you so much for your comments, that makes sense a lot to me. I gonna amend my code and give it a test later.

I tested with 2000 publishes and it works as we expected. I think the issue I had before was that I didn't use enough publishes to establish a good comparison.

The documentation says:

Publish publishes msg to the topic asynchronously. Messages are
batched and sent according to the topic's PublishSettings. Publish
never blocks.
[...]
Publish creates goroutines for batching and sending messages. These
goroutines need to be stopped by calling t.Stop().

That means you are leaking goroutines, in the second case more than in the first. You are not comparing sending times, in the first example sending will be batched.
You “benchmark” measures something, but not what you think it does.

Woow, I just realised I made this stupid issue before. Huge thanks for your comments.
